# Find duplicates and delet them while conserving the rest of the data and associated column

Tags: excel, function

I have an Excel file containing a list of articles and references that I need to work with arranged this ways:

```
Matched:       Article:  BarCode:  Code:
AA01123        AA01123   23459544  4533  
AA06789        KK01234   30493282  45643
BB20443        AA06789   12304123  453
CC30313        BB20443   12123434  646453
DD22890        CC30313   12341344  433245
               JH01241   12312312  4324
/end           DD22890   34343442  22244
               GF06789   12341434  24621
               XY12306   12341213  2344

               /etc../
```

The **Matched** column are articles that have already been treated, and **Article** contain the complete list of both article that have been treated (so the ones in **Matched** column) and the one I still need to work on.
I'd like to substrate the one in **Matched** from the complete list so that it only remains ones that I have to treat.

I need a function that find the duplicate between **Matched** and **Article** and delete them with the corresponding **BarCode** and **Code**.
I don't need to sort the other column **BarCode** and **Code** I just need to keep them aligned with their corresponding articles.

It would give something like this:

```
Matched:     Article:  Barcode:  Code:
             KK01234   19341344  433245
             JH01241   17312312  4324
             XY12306   12341213  2344
             GF06789   12341434  24621
```

It could also delete the 1st column since I dont need it I put it like this for clarity.

My problem is that because **Matched** and **Article** dont have the same lenght (about 700 and 1300 lines) I cannot simply find the duplicate through the filtre, and also it wouldn't keep the rest sorted in order.

I went with this so far but it only finds the duplicate and doesn't delete the corresponding data.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),””,INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,C:C,0)))
```

If someone could show me how to improve this function or find another one that would do what I need that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something ideal for your situation would possibly require VBA, which could automate the system and also actually delete rows, but as you are not suggesting that I presume you are unfamiliar with it. I will instead suggest that you use 2 data tables: 1 which hosts all of your raw data, and one which holds only the rows not yet 'dealt with'.

**Setting up your raw Data Table**

First I will assume that your raw data table (starting with the 3 columns 'Article' 'Bar code' and 'Code' in columns A, B, and C) is on sheet1. I will also assume that your list of 'Matched' items is somewhere else - let's say you type it in manually on column A of sheet2. Ideally the Matched column should autopopulate based on what you have already done, but I can't really recommend anything there without knowing how you actually 'deal with' each row.

Next, add in a new column to the right of your raw data column - let's call it column D. This will simply check whether the Article on each row has yet been 'dealt with'. Put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=MATCH(A2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)
```

This will show #N/A if an item has not yet been matched, and will otherwise show a row number finding the spot on Sheet2 where the Article number was entered. We can use this to create a new ordered list which will skip items already entered (ie: where the MATCH function returns something other-than #N/A). Put this in E2 and copy down (leave E1 blank):

```
=IF(ISERROR(D2),E1+1,E1)
```

**Setting up your Results Tab**

Now on your results tab (let's say Sheet3), simply create an index that counts up from 1 to the total number of unresolved items, and use that index to pull the columns from Sheet1 based on column E there. So Sheet3 Column A would look as follows (enter in A2 and leave A1 blank):

```
=IF(A1<MAX(Sheet1!E:E,A+1,"")
```

Then create your headers in B1, C1, and D1, to pull in your data from sheet 1. The INDEX function will pull in the desired row of data, and the MATCH function will find the appropriate row to pull it from. Put this in B2, and drag down/to the right for as many rows and columns as you have data:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH($A2, Sheet1!$E:$E, 0))
```

Because we only want to do this up to the point that data exists, we can wrap the whole function in a check to determine whether column A has yet run out of numbers:

```
=IF($A2>0,INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH($A2, Sheet1!$E:$E, 0)),"")
```

And that's it. You now have an ordered list of only items which have not yet been matched, and you also have a full listing of your original raw data as an audit trail. The only step left is to make the 'Matched Items' list in Sheet2 autopopulate, but that will depend on how you determine when an item is Matched - perhaps this does need to be manual [ie: if you are completing the work outside of Excel].

Comment: Thanks a lot @Grade 'Eh' Bacon, I'll try that right now I just need to translate the formula since my excel is not in english, I'll get back to you as soon I've try it. As for the VBA I read some stuff about it when I was looking for a solution I just assumed it would be easier to use something I already used than learning to use VBA, but if you have an example I could try it as well for the sake of training :)

Comment: @Zoubro As far as VBA goes, I would recommend generally that you not go that route unless you have a specific project which requires it (unlikely), and you have sufficient time to at least learn how to understand a given piece of code as well as write your own. It is better for you to use a solution you understand, even if it is a bit long-winded, rather than to use a short 'ideal' solution which you do not understand.

Comment: I guess you're right I'll try it on my own later, tho right now I'm struggling to  link the 2nd sheet into the formula, I mean that when I try to use the formula I got an #N/A for everything and it tells me Error: value not available, tho I check the links are activated and everything, I dont know where its coming from, I'm using a cracked version of office 2011 for mac.

Comment: Nevermind I put it in a whole other .xls and and it's working fine now! Thanks :)